# Flickering horizontal black lines, streaks on screen (Kali, Tails), not present in other OS

Tags: linux, kali-linux, drivers, xorg, display

As the subject, I have flickering, horizontal small black lines (thin, and also not a complete line, rather small streaks). [Please see the video evidence for better explanation.](https://streamable.com/gnbizc).
This is a fresh kali install, only update and upgrade was executed. I am multi booting Linux Mint Mate and Linux Lite as well and neither of these have the same problem, this only occurs in TailsOS, and Kali on bare metal. Only sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade was executed, then I also installed the latest
[Neofetch here for system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKk44.png)

xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20200714-1+b1).
The flickering black lines are changing positions as well when I change the display settings.
I have tried changing almost every combination of acceptable resolutions, refresh rates, only the place and length of the black lines change. Any ideas how to fix it? Should I try to build Mesa from the latest source? I'm kind of novice on Linux still, just getting into it, and this is the first actual issue I face with it. Any help is appreciated.

```
> └─$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL  
>OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
>OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
>OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.4
>OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
>OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
>OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
>OpenGL core profile extensions:
>OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.3.4
>OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
>OpenGL context flags: (none)
>OpenGL extensions:
>OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 20.3.4
>OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
>OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

> xdpyinfo | grep version
> version number:    11.0
> X.Org version: 1.20.11